# How does a compiler (C/C++) identify a comment?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

If my program has a string s1= "like/*this" , s2="like /*this is a comment */this" and s3 = "like //*this is not a comment"
In s1 and s3, "/*" and "//*" are part of the string.
In s2, It is a comment for the users to be displayed on the output screen.
What algorithm does the c/c++ compiler use for this? (My guess is, the compiler just ignores all text inside "")

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis

Comment: It's called parsing. The details can vary from compiler to compiler and even between versions of the same compiler. This question is too broad.

Comment: could you elaborate incontext of any one compile say gcc?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1510919/694576

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but both `gcc` and `clang` are open source. You'd learn a great deal more by just reading their code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, inside strings there are no comments, all the characters are part of the string. From the C standard, chapter 6.4.9 (Comments):

> Except within a character constant, a string literal, or a comment, the characters /* introduce a comment. The contents of such a comment are examined only to identify multibyte characters and to find the characters */ that terminate it.

Then a similar rule for the `//` comments.

Also, there is a nice foot-note clarifying that since the `/*` is not recognized inside a comment, comments do not nest.

About the algorithm used by compilers... well, when tokenizing the input file, the compiler knows if it is inside a string or not (it must know its own state), is it is easy to switch to *comment mode* or not.

Answer (score 3):

It is the [lexical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) of the compiler. For C, it is tied to the [preprocessing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) (so look into the [libcpp/](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libcpp/) directory of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) source code). Read more about [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) & [abstract syntax trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).

You should read the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) which gives an overview of compilation techniques (we cannot explain them here in a few sentences).

Lexical analysis is often done using finite automaton (corresponding to regular expressions) techniques. In many cases, you could generate the lexical analyzer, e.g. using [flex](https://github.com/westes/flex). Syntax analysis can also be generated, e.g. using [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) (related to stack automaton).

<sup>(BTW, current GCC 6 & 7 are using hand-written lexers and parsers -instead of generating them with e.g. `flex` & `bison` -: first to manage a lot of extra information such as source position, how something has been macro-expanded; also, for better error messages; and perhaps for efficiency)</sup>

If you want detailed explanations about GCC, my [MELT documentation](http://gcc-melt.org/docum.html) web page contain a lot of references. Look also at the [GCC internals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/) documentation and of course download and study the [source](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/) code of *GCC*. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8356360/841108).